# ¿Cómo implementar un generador recursivo en Python?

Tags: python, yield

Estoy implementando en Python el [algoritmo de Floyd-Warshall para hallar caminos mínimos en un grafo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Floyd-Warshall). He tenido un problema escribiendo una función recursiva para imprimir dicho camino mínimo utilizando la **matriz de predecesores** (del inglés [*predecessor matrix*](http://www.programming-algorithms.net/article/45708/Floyd-Warshall-algorithm)):

```
def print_path(p_ij, ii, jj):
     """Recursive function to reconstruct the shortest path from i to j.

     """
     if ii != jj:
        print_path(p_ij, ii, p_ij[ii, jj])

     print(jj)
```

Quería hacerlo con generadores, pero me he topado con algo curioso. Esta forma no funciona, porque **solo imprime el último número**:

```
def build_path(p_ij, ii, jj):
    """Recursive function to reconstruct the shortest path from i to j.

    """
    if ii != jj:
        build_path(p_ij, ii, p_ij[ii, jj])

    yield jj

def print_path(p_ij, ii, jj):
    for jj in build_path(p_ij, ii, jj):
        print(jj)
```

Y esta otra forma (solo cambio `build_path`) me devuelve una lista con un número y un generador, totalmente inútil:

```
def build_path(p_ij, ii, jj):
    """Recursive function to reconstruct the shortest path from i to j.

    """
    if ii != jj:
        yield build_path(p_ij, ii, p_ij[ii, jj])  # <-- Añado un yield

    yield jj
```

¿Cómo puedo conseguir algo equivalente a la primera versión usando generadores?

Comment: Casi quemo cerebro pensando que estas haciendo "sorting recursivo", pero creo que es "shortest" en vez de "sortest"

Comment: Me da que te estaba pasando lo mismo que a mi con los generadores de caliair. El que te imprima solo el último número es por que va mutando el objeto que te devuelve, no creando objetos nuevos, y al final dicho objeto queda con el último estado del generador.. Tampoco estaría de más que explicaras que es p_ij, ii, jj, o usar nombres más explicativos.

Comment: Tienes razón @tinproject, no quería «ensuciar» la pregunta pero creo que me he quedado un poco corto de información y falta contesto. Hoy la completo.

Comment: Hecho @tinproject, se trataba de una parte del algoritmo de Floyd-Warshall (hay poca literatura en español, desgraciadamente). Creo que la pregunta se entiende mejor ahora.

Comment: El problema esta en que con ```yield build_path(p_ij, ii, p_ij[ii, jj])``` estas devolviendo un generador de generadores, no un generador de objetos del tipo de ```jj```. Con _yield from_ 'delega' el generador y no crea generadores de generadores... En resumen, aunque Python es dinámico, los tipos importan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricardo ha dado la clave con su respuesta, que es utilizar [`yield from`, añadido en Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator):

> La PEP 380 añade la expresión `yield from`, que permite a un generador delegar parte de su funcionalidad en otro generador. Esto posibilita factorizar una sección del código que contenga `yield` o ponerlo en un nuevo generador.

Así que la solución final es tan simple como esto:

```
def build_path(p_ij, ii, jj):
    """Recursive function to reconstruct the shortest path from i to j.

    """
    if ii != jj:
        yield from build_path(p_ij, ii, p_ij[ii, jj])  # ¡Ahora sí!

    yield jj
```

En versiones a Python anteriores, se puede seguir esta sintaxis, como comenta @Darkhogg:

```
def build_path(p_ij, ii, jj):
    """Recursive function to reconstruct the sortest path from i to j.

    """
    if ii != jj:
        for ee in build_path(p_ij, ii, p_ij[ii, jj]):
            yield ee

    yield jj
```

Comment: en ausencia de `yield from x` siempre puedes usar `for e in x: yield e` que viene a ser lo mismo.

Comment: Añadido a la respuesta, ¡gracias!

Comment: En general no es 100% equivalente, como se puede comprobar en el texto del [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/), particularmente porque `yield from` puede devolver un resultado y este sistema *no*.

Answer (score 1):

En recursión todo es de atrás hacia adelante:

```
def build_path(matrix, i=0, j=0):
    """Recursive function to reconstruct the sortest path from i to j."""
    try:
        yield matrix[i][j]
        j += 1
        yield from build_path(matrix, i, j) if j < len(matrix[i]) else\
                build_path(matrix, i + 1)
    except IndexError:
        pass

def print_path(matrix):
    for jj in build_path(matrix):
        print(jj)

test_matrix = (
    (1, 2, 3),
    (4, 5, 6),
    (7, 8, 9)
)
print_path(test_matrix)
```

Comment: Precisamente la clave está en `yield from`, voy a poner una solución más simple :) ¡Gracias!

Comment: En tu codigo no consegui entender porque usas un diccionario o mejor dicho porque pasas una tupla como clave a *p_js* `p_ij[ii, jj]`  De Cualquier modo encontre una forma mas compresa de escribir el ejemplo que te pase

Comment: Porque es un array de NumPy, olvidé mencionarlo :/

Comment: jajaja ahi va. Muchas gracias por sacarme esa duda. Abrazo de pato